# Jobs stuck in azure pipeline queue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

currently experiencing an issue with azure pipelines where a job seems to be stuck running stopping other jobs from being processed. The running job has been cancelled yet the agent says it is running, are there any solutions to this? We've tried deleting the 'azure pipelines', turning the agent off and back on again but no luck, is this likely to be an azure bug? We have not hit any caps or limits

Below you can see there is one running job.
[image]

When I click into azure pipelines no processes are running
[image]

[image]
But the agent thinks it is running Job 938 but as can be seen it is not running

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is this a self hosted or an azure agent?

Comment: You can click into the pipeline job 938 to check the status for more details. From the job name, it looks like a release stage.
It could be pending for approval or checks.

Comment: It's an azure agent, seems to have just resolved itself now, no idea what caused it or resolved it.

Comment: For me its same case, Cancelled but azure still considered as running that's why...

Comment: I have just experienced the same. My guess is there is a bug somewhere in the agent/Azure DevOps. Mine is solved automatically after 20-30 mins.

Comment: Happens to me occasionally after cancelling a run. Resolves by itself if you wait long enough. Microsoft is a buggy mess.